# PHP Cannot access variable from another php file in another directory

Tags: php

in **/var/www/** is my **main.php** file:

```
<?php
include("../config/config.php");
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo $user;
?>
```

in **/var/config/** is my **config.php** file

```
<?php
$user = "myUser";
?>
```

When calling main.php in my browser I'm getting a blank site, instead of "myUser".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your document root is set to "/var/www/" then you should work in that directory.

Your code does not work properly because of the "/", on Windows it doesn't matter but on Linux it does and it's different.

Anyway, a more better example would be this:

```
<?php
include("..".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."config".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."config.php");
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo $user;
?>
```

And now main.php will be able to access your config.php on any operating system.

Comment: This still gives me a blank site

Comment: @LisaCleaver That is not possible, I have tested before I posted this... check if you actually have permisions on "/var/config/"

Comment: @LisaCleaver Or even better, move config folder to /var/www/config/ and then call "include("config".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."config.php");"

Comment: My browser returns HTTP ERROR 500. The config file contains a database password as well, that's why I dont want it to be in /www

Comment: Then you have other issues, turn on error_reporting to see what's going on

Comment: @LisaCleaver It doesn't matter if you have sensitive data in your config.php because nobody can access it if you set permisions to 664...

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. The issue was a syntax error in the config file. Missing semicolon.

Comment: @LisaCleaver See, I told you :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/config.php';
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete, and it would not work on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: You can use `realpath` function for that

Comment: This still gives me a blank site as well